# Is PHP 7.4 fully supported?

Tags: php7

We've just updated to PHP7.4 and it seems to be working ok, but without extensive testing it is hard to know.

PHP 7.4 is not even listed on the [requirements and compatibility page](https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/requirements/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not yet officially. If you want to track progress you can subscribe to the ticket at https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/issues/1496 and its subtickets.

If you find some issue feel free to report it in a ticket there.

The money_format issue might be something you could look at. If you're testing I'd look closely at how money amounts are formatted on the screen and in receipts - that kind of thing.